# Around what time did dark skin disappear from Europe?

Tags: human-biology, human-genetics, human-evolution

As Europeans gradually became lighter skinned, there would have been people that still had dark skin. Around what time period did Europeans become completely light skinned?

Comment: This should be relevant: [How europeans evolved white skin)](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2015/04/how-europeans-evolved-white-skin) (http://www.sciencemag.org/news/ 2015).